# How to update on laravel request a unique field on validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to edit a form where I have a post with a title, body and slug, the slug is unique, so if I edit and don't update it, it says It alredy have been taken

I'm trying this on my PostRequest validation:

```
public function rules()
    {
       return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'metaTitle' => 'required',
            'metaDescription' => 'required',
            'slug' => ['required', Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($this->post)],
        ];
    }
```

the function on Post controller is:

```
public function store(PostStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        auth()->user()->posts()->create($validated);
        return redirect()->route('articulos.index');
    }
```

also on my blade update form I have @method('PUT')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this:

```
public function rules()
 {     
       $slug = $this->request->get("slug");

       return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'metaTitle' => 'required',
            'metaDescription' => 'required',
            'slug' => ['required', Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($slug,'slug')],
        ];
  }
```

Comment: works but if u try to add slug that is not unique while creating it throws an error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'dasddas' for key 'posts_slug_unique' but update method works correct

Comment: You are correct - this only will works fine with updaing. I think requests for creating and updating sholud be separated. In case of creating - get rid of '->ignore($slug,'slug')' part

Comment: I did two validation request, postStore and postUpdate and all working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will work

```
public function rules(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'metaTitle' => 'required',
            'metaDescription' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'required|slug|unique:posts,slug,' . $this->post,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Now It says "Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\wamp64\www\item.github\resources\views\manager\posts\list.blade.php)"

Comment: 'slug' => [
                'required',
                'slug',
                Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($this->post, 'id')
            ],

Comment: this->post is your post object id?

Comment: no, its the whole post, tryed what u said now I got different error "Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateSlug does not exist."

Comment: seems like $this-post is empty

Comment: debug and check what you are getting there

Comment: post is empty, from Request $request i get a big object, can access to slug or title for example but not the ID or post

Comment: var_dump($request->get('key') and try

Comment: dunno what's going on, using this in his own class it says "Class App\Http\Requests\PostStoreRequest does not exist"

Comment: var dump this posting and check you getting anything there?

Comment: yes, tryed var_dump($request->get('key'); exit(); on PostStoreRequest.php where I have the rules validation and it throws that error

Comment: Man var_dump($this->post); try this what u getting let me know

Comment: told u, NULL, dunno why i'm sending it from form, <form class="form-horizontal col-12" action="{{ route('articulos.update', $post->id) }}" method="POST"> @csrf
                    @method('PATCH')

Comment: var_dump($request->get('id'); exit(); this try

Comment: throws an error Class App\Http\Requests\PostStoreRequest does not exist"

Comment: in route like this Route::put("user/{id}" , "UserController@update"); ?

Comment: if you are trying to add new then use 'slug' => 'required|slug|unique:posts',

and if you trying to update then 'slug' => 'required|slug|unique:posts,slug,' . $request->id,

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution I have found, using my own validator PostRequest doesn't work so for update I validate inside the update function:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $request->validate([
            'slug' => 'required|unique:posts,slug,' . $id,
            'title' => 'required',
        ]);

         $post = Post::find($id);
         $post->fill($request->all());
         $post->save();
        return redirect()->route('articulos.index');
    }
```

Would be cool to know why this happens and how to solve it, but this is working for now

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for both the `Store` And `Update` Method:

```
'slug' => [ 
    'required', 
    'slug', 
    'unique:posts,slug' . (isset($this->post)  ? ',' . $this->post : ' ') 
],
```

Comment: Can't put this on my PostRequest validation because $this->post is NULL, how can I get it?

Comment: in store method u dont need and update u pass an id then fetch object pass in validation method then  'unique:posts,slug' . (isset($object->slug)  ? ',' . $object-slug : ' ')